# JavaScript - Persistent memory leaks

Tags: javascript, typescript, memory

I have been getting persistent memory leaks with my TypeScript application (3PG). The memory management appears to be flawed.

**Two Applications**:

- 2PG -> https://github.com/theADAMJR/2pg [does not have memory leaks]
- 3PG -> the application in question, [extension of 2PG, has set intervals etc.]

Here is a class of 3PG that uses lots of intervals and could be a cause: https://pastebin.com/Z6K8a2vK

```
private schedule(uuid: string, savedGuild: GuildDocument, interval: number) {
        const task = this.findTask(uuid, savedGuild.id);
        if (!task.timer) return;
 
        task.status = 'ACTIVE';
        task.timeout = setInterval(
            async() => await this.sendTimer(task, savedGuild), interval);
}
```

I was wondering if this code could be the issue, and if so, **what I am doing or should avoid doing** in JavaScript that would **build up memory usage**. Thanks.

---

**Update**: The problem was due to discord.js calling the `ready` event multiple times which built memory up over time. It was also my mistake of not providing enough info to help precisely answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably the fact that all those setInterval calls, will set up a new execution. There are 2 things that you need to do

1. [Clear Intervals](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) for anything that has already done its job and is no longer needed.Hold a reference to the interval objects and clear them when the component is no longer in use
2. Without knowing exacly the business behind your code, consider if setTimeout could be more appropriate for this task

Comment: They are already storing the interval id (`task.timeout = setInterval(`) how do you know they're not clearing it when the task is done?

Comment: well... there is a memory leak... the code in inspection has no reference to clear interval... i dont "know" it, i am guessing it, and i am probably correct i think. Let alone they are storing it, on the task's fields, which i dont think can be referrenced from an other part of their code, since its initialized in the same function

Comment: If we're doing a guessing game, then my bet is on findTask returns same-object, so storing on task is perfectly sensible, but we are not playing guessing game, so I did vote to close this question because we don't have enough information to answer it.

Comment: We are always playing a guessing game, unless somebody provides all relevant code parts... A proper dev will even play the guessing game on his own project when faced with a "new issue, never experienced before". You know that "trial & error" starts with guessing right? Anyway, you did very good by voting to close, as the question is not formed according to the rules, and i did very good throwing a guess here that might help, might not, but its better than him having no feedback at all